# Merging multiple branches from same master

Tags: git

I have created multiple branches (say, b1... bn) from same master (M).

Now, when I merge them, as the job is done, one by one, will my master become M +b1+... bn, or the last merger will overwrite the previous merges, and leave me with M + bn, and all the merges i.e. b1, b2 are lost?

Comment: What do you understand by *"merge"*?

Comment: How are you going to make those merges? Can you post a small example of how you're gonna use git?

Comment: Seems like an easy question to answer just by trying it out and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you merge m with b1 and get mb1 then merge mb1 with b2 to get mb1b2 ... mb1b2...bi, if you did not merge any of the branches then the changes in such branches will not be cumulatively reflected on the master branch